# Oracle Update Query with Replace function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have employee table with following records

```
eid | ename | egender
1   | abd   | m
2   | xvc   | f
3   | sdfg  | m
4   | sdf   | f
```

I want to change egender from `m` to `f`, and from `f` to `m`. How would I write an UPDATE query?

Answer (score 1):

A simple query should work:

```
UPDATE employee
SET egender = IF(egender = 'm', 'f', 'm')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use if statement

```
UPDATE employee SET egender = IF(egender = 'f', 'm', 'f');
```